# Avoiding type II error when regressors are correlated

Tags: regression, type-i-and-ii-errors

Consider a regression of the form

$$
y = a + bX + \gamma D + e
$$

Where $D = \{0,1\}$ is a dummy variable and we are interested in detecting if $\gamma \neq 0$. If in fact $\gamma \neq 0$, then the likelihood of committing a Type II error (failure to reject $H_0: \gamma = 0$) increases as the correlation between $D$ and $X$ grows. The question is if there is an alternative test with more power so that the chance of committing a Type II error is lower? And if so, what is the tradeoff in terms of increasing the chance of a Type I error?

Comment: Are you asking about ways to deal with multicollinearity?

Comment: To an extent yes, but in this setup we know that every variable in $X$ is relevant for predicting $y$, so there will be no opportunity to change $X$ to reduce correlation with $D$. Also, the test on $\gamma$ is the only thing that is of interest.

Comment: Have you considered ridge regression?

Comment: Mark, can you elaborate on how ridge regression would help in this case? If I had a number of collinear variables and I wanted to do variable selection for the most important ones I might use ridge regression, but in this instance we want to leave the $X$ matrix unchanged, as all variables in it have a clear causal relationship for $y$.

Comment: Another point to make is that Guass-Markov assumptions are assumed to be satisfied, so the OLS estimator is BLUE. So I guess I'm asking is it possible to have a lower variance estimator for $\gamma$ in particular, even if I already have the most efficient estimate of the entire coefficient vector $\beta$.